# How far apart can pollination partners be (fruit trees)?

Tags: fruit-trees, pollination

I am running out of space for fruit trees - apples, pears, plums - in one location but have some more space a few tens of metres away, with a large hedge separating the two areas.

To what extent does distance between two pollination partners impact pollination and what distances are considered normal/desirable?

Comment: This can depend on the plant. For example, I have 3 fenale native (US) hollies planted 200m from their male pollinator and they routinely set fruit (they're non-wind pollinated). What fruit trees are you asking about?

Comment: It depends whether they are pollinated by wind or insects. For example honey bees typically forage up to 2 miles from the hive. Studies of solitary wild bee species have recorded distances between 100 and 1200 meters from the nest for different species.

Comment: added a bit of detail

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend planting them within 100 ft, ideally closer to 50 ft for better pollination!